# Shell, Concatenating 2 strings to reference a 3rd variable

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I am trying to do the following in my script:

```
#/bin/bash -x
var1=www
var2=www2
var3=www3
var4=www4
for i in 1 2 3 4; do
   echo \$var$i
done
```

Obviously, this doesn't work as expected and results in the following output:

```
$var1
$var2
$var3
$var4
```

How can I dynamically reference the variables in my loop?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
$ cat indirection.bash
#!/bin/bash -x

var1=www
var2=www2
var3=www3
var4=www4
for i in 1 2 3 4; do
        s="var${i}"
        echo "${!s}"
done
```

```
$ ./indirection.bash
www
www2
www3
www4
```

Comment: How does your script work without `!` in shebang!?

Comment: @sasha.sochka Copy-paste mistake from the OP's code...fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You could use an array:

```
#/bin/bash -x

declare -a vars=(
    www
    www2
    www3
    www4
)

for var in "${vars[@]}"; do
   echo "$var"
done
```

Or iterate with index:

```
for i in "${!vars[@]}"; do
    echo "${vars[$i]}"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Normally shell expands variable only once. You can use indirect expand or ask shell to expand it one more time, for example:

```
eval "val=\$var$i"; echo "$val";
```

instead of just:

```
echo "\$var$i"
```

This method is very portable, but uses <strike>evil</strike> `eval`.

Using indirect expansion as shown in other answers (see Parameter Expansion in [man bash](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/bash.1.html))  `${!VAR_NAME}` is a good solution, when portability is not necessary and you are allowed to use BASH extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Use an [associative array](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006). There's no good reason to generate variable names like this.

There do exist hash table implementations such as [this one](http://www.mirbsd.org/cvs.cgi/contrib/hosted/tg/assockit.ksh?rev=1.8;content-type=text%2Fplain) that are perhaps marginally less ugly than abusing your shell's internal symbol table as a hash map directly through eval. This particular one I haven't fully analyzed in detail and may be doing that on some level - using nameref resolution it seems, but is nevertheless an improvement.

Comment: Yes, there is. If you're in a system that has Bash 3.2, not 4, and you do not have permission to install a newer version, you NEED this.

Comment: lol! I would find a better way.

Comment: What 'better' way when you do not have permission to update bash? I am curious.

Comment: Depends what the system is for. A heavily restricted system is unsuitable as a daily driver for my work so I wouldn't waste time adapting workflow to something less powerful than what I get replacing the whole thing with a raspberry pi. For less important purposes my standard configuration system includes automation for deploying important utilities such as the shell for various limited environments, containers, and vms. If I can't even change my user account's shell I'll force the change with `nss_wrapper`, `proot` or a custom LD_PRELOAD.

Comment: "A heavily restricted system is unsuitable as a daily driver for my work so I wouldn't waste time adapting workflow to something less powerful than what I get replacing the whole thing with a raspberry pi."

XD oh my... you must be a kid, haha. I'll leave it at that.

Comment: Perhaps you're not allowed a shell for a reason.

Comment: "Perhaps you're not allowed db access for a reason", "Perhaps you're not allowed instance access for a reason", etc. 
When you work business to business, you have to adapt to what the other side provides. Get it now?

Comment: I'm not interested in the dysfunctional operation of your organization. If you want to know how to write code properly, that I can help with. Ideally not in this comment section.

Comment: "I'm not interested in the dysfunctional operation of your organization." Yeah, you just come up to places like Samsung or Tesla bossing around asking for root password to have things your way or no way XD. Have a good life, kiddo.

Comment: I do not have to ask. I implement policies that maximize the productivity of teams. I do not hire people that lack the technical competence and integrity to make common sense decisions about their usage of business systems and task them with authoring code. I do not hire people such as yourself, that would compromise the integrity of our architecture to satisfy nonsensical bureaucratic ends. I also do not normally give business advice for free. If you want more nontechnical help, my services are available for a price.  Frankly at this point I've lost all interest. Your attitude is disgusting.

Comment: " I do not hire people that lack the technical competence and integrity to make common sense decisions about their usage of business systems and task them with authoring code." 

So you tell your clients how to run their business? Wow. 

"I also do not normally give business advice for free." 
Hold your horses, you haven't given any advice here at all. 

"Your attitude is disgusting." << I bet your customers find yours charming XD

Comment: I know ur trollin and all but could've chosen a decent rationale, such as the license. Though you wouldn't be using Apple's OS in your product and could just choose a different shell. Instead it's "I have a terrible job and my boss is an idiot and I'm a braindamaged Mac fanboy that acts like a toddler so nobody trusts me because I think ridiculous access levels are required to run a different shell". Quite a story kiddo. You should make a comedy film. Would watch!

Comment: You're the one telling the other part of a B2B relationship that it's your way or the highway. 
I've been there with such requirements. No company will give you access to do as you please being someone from outside their company just because that's what you 'want'. 
You have to make do. 
Declaring variable names like this, for instance. 
That's why I call you kiddo, kiddo: because you learn pretty early in this job about stupid situations like this, where they don't let you update anything and you have to declare variables like this.

Comment: As me being a Mac user (after most of my Pro life being a Linux user), alright? I believe being a man's OS user before using this OS on training wheels shielded me from being a toddler, doesn't it?
Kids these days XD